# Hibernate: how to perform select through the whole hierarchy of objects?

Tags: hibernate, select

I have following structure:

```
abstract class Entity {
    Map<Language,MetaData> metaData;
}

class MetaData {
    private String name;
    ...setters & getters
}

class A extends Entity {
    private Set<B> b;
    private String name;
}

class B extends Entity {
    private Set<C> c;
    private String name;
}

class C extends Entity {
    private String name;
}
```

let's say we select A (HQL) where Language = 'ru'. How to select rest of hierarchy with the same condition (Language = ru)? Is that possible without building of a long queries like "FROM A a JOIN B b JOIN C c etc"?

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be closed. I made a simple converter to extract necessary data from the result set.